# Trying to setup Eclipse for Minecraft modding

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

I've been trying to get into minecraft modding for the past few weeks and can't seem to get past the first step, setting up a workspace with eclipse. First I had to realize that tutorials on the matter said to use the setupDecompWorkspace command, which I now know to be deprecated- that was an easy fix.

Now that I'm past most of the setup process I've hit a brick wall. when trying to run the game with runClient I get the following message https://prnt.sc/1gnm5gg

note that these are the things I've checked and tried:

- Ensuring that I have the proper forge version, which in my case is 1.12.2
- Setting my installed JRE and execution environment to the proper JDK1.8
- Set MC_VERSION to 1.12 and Working directory to 'rootFolder'\run
- done gradlew genEclipseRun and gradlew eclipse to setup the proper folders
- tried adding a 'main' function to the example mod (It is removed in this instance but it didn't work either)

Every tutorial I can find suggests doing one of these things, with no avail, I've been at this for days and need some assistance. Any help is incredibly appreciated!

Comment: Hmm. I don't know if questions relating to Eclipse are more suitable for the Gamedev stack, or just Stack Overflow. Arqade doesn't really have much experience with modding tools - and questions related to Modded Minecraft troubleshooting are explicitly off-topic. I think this question is going to get bounced around a few sites.

Comment: I would recommend reading the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse/info) for Eclipse available on StackOverflow, and then review some of their [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eclipse+setup) related to setup. If all else fails, it appears that questions related to setup of Eclipse aren't frowned upon there. As it currently stands, I don't think this post is a quality post for SO yet, you may want to revise your question following SO guidelines and then ask a moderator to migrate it for you.

Comment: Note that 'modded Minecraft' is different from 'modding Minecraft' - as far as I know there is nothing off-topic about asking for help when you want to mod a game and encounter a problem (technical problems with modded Minecraft are too difficult to reproduce). Modding is also different from 'game development'. Vote to leave open.

Comment: @Joachim check the tour page, Arqade is about gaming. Modding a game is not gaming. This question probably belongs to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Aesithr the log shows an OpenGL problem (no idea if that's normal), a null pointer exception related to the language (maybe you need to define another environment variable?), and says that a game crash file was generated (have you checked it?). I have never used Eclipse to mod Minecraft so I can't really help you, but if it was me, I'd try to investigate those.

Comment: @AJPerez The Tour page is a broad introduction to the site, and not an authoritative source on its own. Questions about the act of modding (not *creating* mods) are also fine (within certain parameters that can be found on [Meta]) - that's why we have the very specific close-reason of technical support for modded Minecraft, and not for other games.